# How to call a PHP function in WordPress when you click on a button?

Tags: wp-autop

How to process the `textarea` field with the standard WordPress function `wpautop()` when clicking the `button`?

Here's the form:

```
<textarea id="my_ta">Lorem ipsum!</textarea>
<button id="button_processing_ta">Обработать</button>
```

Here's the handler (to function.php):

```
<?php
  function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script>
      document.getElementById( 'button_processing_ta' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        let my_ta = document.getElementById( 'my_ta' );

        // ???
        wpautop( my_ta.value );
      });
    </script>
  <?php }

  add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'my_action_javascript', 99 );
?>
```

Sorry for my English...

Comment: you would need to make a request to the server in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) which uses `admin-ajax.php`. This is a way for you to interact with WordPress via a javascript request to WordPress.